# Simple Protocol Concept in Java for this setup

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

i need some idea/suggestion regarding the implementation of any simple/easy to use setup for such system:

[image]

I have two machines, where one will send commands (can be commands, configuration files, text, xml etc) (I have to decide in which way the commands should work) and the other will implement those command. However this is not a completely interactive terminal application, the sender just need to know if it was executed fine or not.

Also RPC is not an option, do i simply go by implementing client/server socket concept??
Is there any well known library to help realize such scenraio in Java? or may be some web server and http based communication??

Any suggestions for opensource libraries to realize such scenario?

Comment: What's wrong with TCP or HTTP (which uses TCP)?

Comment: yes http is an idea, but wont it require full fledge implementation of the protocol, and would it be resource intencive?? can you suggest any good library?

Comment: Java gives you a full HTTP implementation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: @MattBall, on the server end, this would require to setup a web server, like apache i guess? is it possible to run server through java process as well??

Comment: You can create a Cient/Server part in Java and implement a Protocol using JAXB: http://jaxb.java.net/ (Basically this translates Java classes to xml messages and vice versa)

Comment: Thank you i found this resource, mostly it will serve my purpose, so i will add this as an answer:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use sockets or any other TCP messaging service, you will get guarantied message delivery, and then all you need is to write the response on the server end and send it back.

Comment: hey thanks, you were right, i really didn't needed any library

Answer (score 0):

The [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) project. MINA's API is lower level and a great deal complicated. Even the simplest client/server will require a lot more code to be written. MINA also is not integrated with a robust serialization framework and doesn't intrinsically support RMI.

The [Priobit](https://code.google.com/p/pyronet/) project is a minimal layer over NIO. It provides TCP networking, but without the higher level features. Priobit requires all network communication to occur on a single thread.

The [Java Game Networking project](https://code.google.com/p/jgn/) is a higher level library. JGN does not have as simple of an API.

[KryoNet](https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) is a Java library that provides a clean and simple API for efficient TCP and UDP client/server network communication using NIO.