# cross language api for this client server communication model

Tags: java, client-server

my question is following up from this question:
[Simple Protocol Concept in Java for this setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297928/simple-protocol-concept-in-java-for-this-setup)

The idea is exactly the same i.e client will send request and server respond with some information:
[image]

However i want a well known protocol implemtation such that the server/client can be implemented in any programming langguage. So that client Running java can communicate over TCP/IP sockets to remote app written in C e.g.

for this reason, can you recommend any well known opensource implementation?

Comment: Well..... TCP/IP works like that.....

Comment: Consider using RESTful HTTP.

Comment: If not REST, then have you looked up Netty: http://netty.io/

Answer (score 1):

Just few tips:

- Rest interface: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
- Corba: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture
- Apache Thrift: http://thrift.apache.org/
- Google Protocol Buffers: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
- your own implementation over tcp...

Answer (score 0):

it depend on your architecture and your requirement, you can use TCP protocol directly, Http is another choice, if your server deployed on a http server, i recommend using web service. i hope my answer will give you some ideas.